# Sorting Algorithm according to match/mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, cluster-analysis

The data I'm working on represent the presence or the absence of some species in 5 habitats. I want to obtain clusters according to the shared zones between them, basically i want to maximize the matches between elements for each species.
This is the original dataset
[image: Initial Dataset]

And this is the type of sorting I'm looking for
[image: Desired Sorting]
I managed to obtain 3 groups by simply sorting on the numbers of occupied zones and then manually fixing evident errors.
This very simplified algorithm only worked because occupied zones are always contiguous, and some common pattern are present.

At first I thought this problem was somewhat similar to [Sequence Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment), but I can't really think of any way to apply those algorythm to my case. Furthermore I'd also like to find an automated way to cluster those data into 3 groups, but this is not strictly necessary.

The real challenge is sorting this [new Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06aZb.png) that contains gaps.
I think that the best method should:

- Count the number of matches and mismatches between each possible couple of species
- Find the species with most matches with the first one and set them next to each other
- Repeat with the second species (the one just repositioned) excluding the check with the first species (to avoid infinite loops), and so on...

```
## Original df
    Species Zones array
0   A   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1   B   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2   C   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
3   D   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
4   E   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
5   F   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
6   G   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
7   H   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
8   I   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
9   J   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
10  K   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
11  L   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
12  M   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
13  N   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
14  O   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
15  P   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
16  Q   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
17  R   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
18  S   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
19  T   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
20  U   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]


## Sorted df
  Species   Zones array
0   A   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1   B   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2   C   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
3   D   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
4   E   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
5   F   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
6   G   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
7   H   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
8   I   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
9   J   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
10  K   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
11  L   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
12  M   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
13  N   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
14  O   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
15  P   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
16  Q   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
17  R   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
18  S   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
19  T   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
20  U   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

## New gapped df
    Species Prey
0   A   [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
1   B   [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
2   C   [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
3   D   [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
4   E   [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5   F   [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
6   G   [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7   H   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
8   I   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
9   J   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
10  K   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
11  L   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12  M   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
13  N   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
14  O   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
15  P   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
16  Q   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
17  R   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
18  S   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
19  T   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
20  U   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: add demo dataframe instead of pics

Comment: Sure, I'm creating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this problem in a simple yet appropriate way (I'm sure there may be better algorithms though). I check the number of matches between each couple of boolean vectors:

```py
n=len(diet_bool_df['Prey'])
match_mtx = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)] #empty matrix nxn

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
#this gives a vector containing 1 for a match and 0 for a mismatch position-wise
        match_vec = [int(diet_bool_df['Boolean Diet'][i][k]==diet_bool_df['Prey'][j][k]) for k in range(len(diet_bool_df['Prey'][i]))]
#the sum of all 1 gives the number of matches between each couple (i,j)
        match_mtx[i][j] = sum(match_vec)
```

Since there are 9 preys there will be a maximum of 9 matches, which will indicate identical diets. This new matrix now can be actually clusterized with kmeans because data are isotropic and all assumptions should be met.

```
def plot_match_cluster():
    fig= go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
        z=match_mtx,
    ))
    fig.show()
```

[image: Match Matrix as a heatmap]

```
kmeans = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(match_mtx)
```

The new clusterized data looks like this
[Clusterized Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I0Qd.png)

NB. Interestingly enough the initial sorting I decided according to the number of preys is a good indicator in this scenario to create clusters. This is only true with 3 clusters though.

Comment: After some more in-depth analysis, I noticed it's still not correct to use kmean on a similarity matrix. The correct method should be a hierarchical algorithm or a spectral method,

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to cluster, and unless you have a special case it is probably best to use an off-the-shelf approach. Here is an example using kmeans clustering, setting `k=3` for your use case. The solution uses a lot of packages which you may need to install. sklearn is used for the kmeans-clustering, then the rest of the imports are for plotting.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.cluster

from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'A':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'B':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'C':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'D':[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    'E':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'F':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'G':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'H':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'I':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'J':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'K':[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    'L':[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    'M':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'N':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'O':[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
    'P':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'Q':[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
    'R':[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    'S':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'T':[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
    'U':[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
}).T #transposing to be species as rows and zones as columns

#gapped species
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
    'B':[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
    'C':[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
    'D':[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
    'E':[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'F':[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
    'G':[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'H':[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'I':[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'J':[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
    'K':[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'L':[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'M':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'N':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
    'O':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'P':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'Q':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
    'R':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'S':[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'T':[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'U':[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
}).T #transposing to be species as rows and zones as columns 

#Cluster by kmeans with k=3
kmeans = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(df)
cluster_labels = pd.Series(kmeans.labels_+1, index=df.index)

#Prepare for plotting
plot_data = df.multiply(cluster_labels,axis=0)
sorted_plot_data = plot_data.loc[cluster_labels.sort_values().index]

myColors = (
    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), #0-value color
    (0.4, 0.0, 0.4, 1.0), #cluster 1 color
    (0.0, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0), #cluster 2 color
    (0.4, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0), #cluster 3 color
)
my_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', myColors, len(myColors))

#Unsorted Heatmap
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = sns.heatmap(
    
    data = plot_data.T,
    cmap=my_cmap,
    cbar=False,
)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.title('Species in order colored by k-means cluster')
plt.show()
plt.close()

#Sorted Heatmap
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = sns.heatmap(
    data = sorted_plot_data.T,
    cmap=my_cmap,
    cbar=False,
)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.title('Species sorted and colored by k-means cluster, sorted alphabetically within cluster')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Output plots
[image: ungrouped]

[image: grouped]

Comment: That's a smart solution, but at first I didn't want to use k-means because the algorithm only works on the assumption of isotropic data, and I think also similar variances along the 2 axes. Here one of the 2 dimensions is 'ABCD...' and it's a conventional axis. I'm pretty sure It's violating some assumptions.